# Which ascetic sect should one join to get Moksha?

Tags: moksha, sanyasi

I think for getting Moksha one needs to join some ascetic sect. Since there are many fraud,dubious sect present in today's world.

So, Which sect is the authentic one ?

Or Is it best to become independent ascetic after studying the scriptures ?

Comment: Opnion based but any guruparampara need deeksha in particular mantra saranagathi to particular deity you need understand what their philosophy saying and ask fundamental questions about the primary philosophy like avaita saying jagat mitya brahma stayam naparah and you need to question this assumption based on your experience

Answer (score 2):

It is best to join recognized sects who follow Sri Sankaracharya, Sri Ramanujacharya, Sri Madhvacharya etc. Ramakrishna Math is also very good.